# finding selected items in Telerik RadGridView using MVVM pattern

Tags: mvvm, telerik, selecteditem, caliburn.micro, radgridview

I am using a Telerik RadGridView in my application and it has a GridViewSelectColumn item in it, which allows me to select various items in the grid. I have a button that operates on this selection, but am not sure how to get the list of selected items. The problem is that I am using an MVVM pattern with Caliburn.Micro. Do I need to find the control in the view and traverse the list of selected items? That seems like a lot of work for a simple task. I would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 11):

The problem with Telerik's RadGridView is, that its SelectedItem collection is read-only, so you cannot bind two-way to SelectedItems.

A workaround for this is to use a custom Behavior to do the synchronization between RadGridView and your ViewModels SelectedItem collection

You may use this Behavior:

```
// Behavior for synchronizing a RadDataGrid's SelectedItems collection with a SelectedItems collection of the ViewModel (the Network)
// The problem is, that RadDataGrid.SelectedItems is a read-only collection and therefore cannot be used for two-way binding.

class SelectedSyncBehavior
    : Behavior<RadGridView>
{
    bool _collectionChangedSuspended = false;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.CollectionChanged += GridSelectedItems_CollectionChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Getter/Setter for DependencyProperty, bound to the DataContext's SelectedItems ObservableCollection
    /// </summary>
    public INotifyCollectionChanged SelectedItems
    {
        get { return (INotifyCollectionChanged)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dependency Property "SelectedItems" is target of binding to DataContext's SelectedItems
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(INotifyCollectionChanged), typeof(SelectedSyncBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(OnSelectedItemsPropertyChanged));

    /// <summary>
    /// PropertyChanged handler for DependencyProperty "SelectedItems"
    /// </summary>
    private static void OnSelectedItemsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        INotifyCollectionChanged collection = args.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (collection != null)
        {
            // Hook to the Network's SelectedItems
            collection.CollectionChanged += (target as SelectedSyncBehavior).ContextSelectedItems_CollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Will be called, when the Network's SelectedItems collection changes
    /// </summary>
    void ContextSelectedItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_collectionChangedSuspended) return;    // Don't react recursively to CollectionChanged events

        _collectionChangedSuspended = true;

        // Select and unselect items in the grid
        if (e.NewItems != null)
            foreach (object item in e.NewItems)
                AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);

        if (e.OldItems != null)
            foreach (object item in e.OldItems)
                AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Remove(item);

        _collectionChangedSuspended = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Will be called when the GridView's SelectedItems collection changes
    /// </summary>
    void GridSelectedItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_collectionChangedSuspended) return;    // Don't react recursively to CollectionChanged events

        _collectionChangedSuspended = true;

        // Select and unselect items in the DataContext
        if (e.NewItems != null)
            foreach (object item in e.NewItems)
                (SelectedItems as IList).Add(item);

        if (e.OldItems != null)
            foreach (object item in e.OldItems)
                (SelectedItems as IList).Remove(item);

        _collectionChangedSuspended = false;
    }

}
```

Use this Behavior with RadGridViews like this:

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
   <behaviors:SelectedSyncBehavior SelectedItems="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedItems}" />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: this should be the selected answer! The telerik blogs all seemed to be lacking the complete solution found here.

Comment: Don't forget to instantiate the collection SelectedItems property is binding to, wasted 15 minutes on that...

Answer (score 2):

Add a bool IsSelected to the item in your collection:

```
 public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }

 private BindableCollection<Customer> _customers;
        public BindableCollection<Customer> Customers
        {
            get { return _customers; }
            set
            {
                _customers = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Customers);
            }
        }
```

[sample code - bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/dbeattie/cmdemo/src)

[download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_e5C-QWr9KR3d5TmhJNDc0ZjA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I'm trying to get this working. Could you show the XAML please as I don't seem to be able to get the binding to work.
Alternatively could you make the source available as a download without having to go through bitbucket as I can't get at it there.

Comment: @Dave added a download of the repo

Comment: Thanks Derek. I seem to be misunderstanding something. I see you have an IsSelected property on Customer, but I cannot find a binding to it in the XAML.

Comment: @Dave I believe that's being handled by Telerik control and autogenerated columns.  The bool prop IsSelected will display as a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaned up copy of @Knasterbax's class with explicit private modifiers and null propagation:

```
// Behavior for synchronizing Telerik RadDataGrid's SelectedItems collection 
//  with a SelectedItems collection of the ViewModel.   
public class SelectedSyncBehavior : Behavior<RadGridView>
{
    private bool collectionChangedSuspended;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems",
        typeof(INotifyCollectionChanged), typeof(SelectedSyncBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(OnSelectedItemsPropertyChanged));

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.CollectionChanged += GridSelectedItems_CollectionChanged;
    }

    public INotifyCollectionChanged SelectedItems
    {
        get { return (INotifyCollectionChanged)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnSelectedItemsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var collection = args.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (collection == null) return;
        var selectedSyncBehavior = target as SelectedSyncBehavior;
        if (selectedSyncBehavior != null) collection.CollectionChanged += selectedSyncBehavior.ContextSelectedItems_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void ContextSelectedItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (collectionChangedSuspended) return;    // Don't react recursively to CollectionChanged events

        collectionChangedSuspended = true;

        if (e.NewItems != null)
            foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);

        if (e.OldItems != null)
            foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
                AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Remove(item);

        collectionChangedSuspended = false;
    }

    private void GridSelectedItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (collectionChangedSuspended) return;    // Don't react recursively to CollectionChanged events

        collectionChangedSuspended = true;

        if (e.NewItems != null)
            foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
            {
                var list = SelectedItems as IList;
                list?.Add(item);
            }

        if (e.OldItems != null)
            foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
            {
                var list = SelectedItems as IList;
                list?.Remove(item);
            }

        collectionChangedSuspended = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleanup version of the answer above.  This removes underscores, adds qualifiers, accessors, braces, etc.

```
public class SelectedItemsBehavior : Behavior<RadGridView>
{
    private bool collectionChangedSuspended;

    /// <summary>
    /// Called after the behavior is attached to an AssociatedObject.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Override this to hook up functionality to the AssociatedObject.
    /// </remarks>
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.CollectionChanged += this.GridSelectedItemsCollectionChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Getter/Setter for DependencyProperty, bound to the DataContext's SelectedItems ObservableCollection
    /// </summary>
    public INotifyCollectionChanged SelectedItems
    {
        get => (INotifyCollectionChanged)this.GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty);
        set => this.SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dependency Property "SelectedItems" is target of binding to DataContext's SelectedItems
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(INotifyCollectionChanged), typeof(SelectedItemsBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(OnSelectedItemsPropertyChanged));

    /// <summary>
    /// PropertyChanged handler for DependencyProperty "SelectedItems"
    /// </summary>
    private static void OnSelectedItemsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        INotifyCollectionChanged collection = args.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (collection != null)
        {
            collection.CollectionChanged += ((SelectedItemsBehavior)target).ContextSelectedItemsCollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Will be called, when the Network's SelectedItems collection changes
    /// </summary>
    private void ContextSelectedItemsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.collectionChangedSuspended)
        {
            return; 
        }

        this.collectionChangedSuspended = true;

        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (object item in e.NewItems)
            {
                this.AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Add(item);
            }
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (object item in e.OldItems)
            {
                this.AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.Remove(item);
            }
        }

        this.collectionChangedSuspended = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Will be called when the GridView's SelectedItems collection changes
    /// </summary>
    private void GridSelectedItemsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.collectionChangedSuspended)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.collectionChangedSuspended = true;

        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (object item in e.NewItems)
            {
                ((IList)this.SelectedItems).Add(item);
            }
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (object item in e.OldItems)
            {
                ((IList)this.SelectedItems).Remove(item);
            }
        }

        this.collectionChangedSuspended = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a situation where you cannot add boolean (ObseravbleCollection for example.

Please take a look at [this](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/10-05-31/how-to-synchronize-your-ui-selected-items-with-your-data-context-using-mvvm-and-blend-behaviors-for-silverlight-and-wpf.aspx) solution.

Comment: Has anybody got that blog post working? I gave it a go and the RadGridView does not even seem to have a SelectedItems property...